# Google Analytics api not returning data as Google Analytics interface

Tags: google-analytics, google-analytics-api

I've been running the following

[query run through google api](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5QUoP.png)

However, the results I get are very different from what I see in Google Analytics interface. The query returns only 2 event categories, whereas in the interface there are 6 of them.

I've checked the time frame, the view id and the segment, but everything matches. Why doesn't google analytics api retrieve the same information as the interface?

Comment: Does the result contain sampled data?

Comment: No, it doesn't.